# Two forms for a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm having the following code. 
If I submit the first form (the one with the A and B options) the second query works fine, but when I submit the second form (the one with the date) the query is not working because I lose the value of variable `$XStocLa`.

I want to be able to select an option A or B and this option to be saved in the session and then to be able to select different dates in the second form, but keeping the value of the `$XStocLa` I selected before until I choose the other value or reset the session.

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="XStocLa" id="StocLa">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>

<form method="post">
    <input type="date" name="ordersmonth">
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['ordersmonth'])) {
   $OrdersMonth = $_POST['ordersmonth'];    
   $sql ="SELECT * FROM " .$OrderTable. " WHERE YEAR(Date) = YEAR('" .$OrdersMonth. "') AND MONTH(DATE) = MONTH('" .$OrdersMonth. "') AND StocLa = '$XStocLa' ORDER BY Date DESC, ID ASC";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
} else {
   $sql ="SELECT * FROM " .$OrderTable. " WHERE StocLa = '$XStocLa' ORDER BY Date DESC, ID ASC";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
?>
```

I am sorry if I didn't explain well I hope you understand.

Comment: Why are you using two different forms?

Comment: Then start writing your code to use sessions / cookies? We aren't gonna write it for you.

Comment: no need to use 2 forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using 1 form only:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="XStocLa" id="StocLa">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date" name="ordersmonth">
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>

<?php    
if(isset($_POST['ordersmonth']) && !empty($_POST['ordersmonth'])) {
   $OrdersMonth = $_POST['ordersmonth'];
   $sql ="SELECT * FROM " .$OrderTable. " WHERE YEAR(Date) = YEAR('" .$OrdersMonth. "') AND MONTH(DATE) = MONTH('" .$OrdersMonth. "') AND StocLa = '$XStocLa' ORDER BY Date DESC, ID ASC";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
} else {
   $sql ="SELECT * FROM " .$OrderTable. " WHERE StocLa = '$XStocLa' ORDER BY Date DESC, ID ASC";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: @GrimVic glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You use 2 forms so all the var in the 2 forms are separate. Re-write your code to use only 1 form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in just one form with two submit button like this

**Note**: I just name the submit button `select1` and `select2`

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="XStocLa" id="StocLa">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="select1"  value="Select">

    <input type="date" name="ordersmonth">
    <input type="submit" name="select2" value="Select">
</form>
<?php
//I just assume your that $OrderTable is order_tbl
$OrderTable = 'order_tbl';


//Check if select1 has been set or clicked
if(isset($_POST['select1'])) {
    $XStocLa= $_POST['XStocLa'];
    $OrdersMonth = $_POST['ordersmonth'];

    $sql ="SELECT * FROM " .$OrderTable. " WHERE YEAR(Date) = YEAR('" .$OrdersMonth. "') AND MONTH(DATE) = MONTH('" .$OrdersMonth. "') AND StocLa = '$XStocLa' ORDER BY Date DESC, ID ASC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

//check if select2 has been set or clicked
} else if(isset($_POST['select2'])){
    $XStocLa= $_POST['XStocLa'];


    $sql ="SELECT * FROM " .$OrderTable. " WHERE StocLa = '$XStocLa' ORDER BY Date DESC, ID ASC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works too but Pathik Vejani's solution is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your php code. just try it. but like what they say, you can do it on 1 post only.

```
if(isset($_POST['ordersmonth'])) {
        $OrdersMonth = $_POST['ordersmonth'];

        $sql ="SELECT * FROM " .$OrderTable. " WHERE YEAR(Date) = YEAR('" .$OrdersMonth. "') AND MONTH(DATE) = MONTH('" .$OrdersMonth. "') AND StocLa = '$_POST['XStocLa']' ORDER BY Date DESC, ID ASC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    } else {
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM " .$OrderTable. " WHERE StocLa = '$_POST['XStocLa']' ORDER BY Date DESC, ID ASC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
```